# Find a simple expression for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} k(k-1)\binom{n}{k}$ for $n\geq0$

Tags: combinatorics

Find a simple expression for $\sum_{k=0}^{n} k(k-1)\binom{n}{k}$ for $n\geq0$.

My intuition is to somehow make use of the fact that $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n}{k}\binom{n - 1}{k - 1}$. Can I simply replace the $\binom{n}{k}$ with this identity and solve from there somehow?

Comment: Your procedure will work, doing it again gives $\frac{n(n-1)}{k(k-1)}\binom{n-2}{k-2}$. That cancels the $k(k-1)$ on top. Note that the original sum really starts at $k=2$. Now the sum $\sum_{k=2}^{n-2} \binom{n-2}{k-2}$ is familiar, particularly if we reindex.

Answer (score 3):

Start with $$(1+x)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}x^k$$

And take derivatives (twice) on both sides. Then evaluate at $x=1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Find a combinatorial argument for which
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{2} = \binom{n}{2}\,2^{n-2} $$
then use the previous identity.

<sup>Sub-Hint: in how many ways can we paint $n$ balls in red, green or blue in such a way that there are exactly two red balls?</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,\tfrac{1}{2})$ be a binomial random variable. You are after $$2^n\mathbb{E}[X(X-1)] = 2^n(\mathbb{E}[X^2]-\mathbb{E}[X]) = 2^n(\mathbb{V}[X] + \mathbb{E}[X]^2 - \mathbb{E}[X]).$$ Since expectation and variance are additive, it is easy to calculate $\mathbb{E}[X] = \tfrac{n}{2}$ and $\mathbb{V}[X] = \tfrac{n}{4}$. Therefore
$$2^n\mathbb{E}[X(X-1)] = 2^n\left(\frac{n}{4} + \frac{n^2}{4} - \frac{n}{2}\right) = 2^{n-2}n(n-1).$$